# Will R0 register always be used before anything else?

Tags: arm, embedded, armcc

Does the compiler always use R0 in order?

Comment: Say what? Are you asking about ARM ABI or something else? Could you clarify the question, possibly provide some examples?

Comment: According to the AAPCS protocol, the compiler calls function after save the data from r0 to r3 automatically.
And If the size of the function is small and r3 is no need to be used, it can skip
saving the data in r3 register.
In this situation I have a question. If R0 is no need to be used, Is R0 also can skip
saving the data? If not, please tell me some cases. I'll wait for your answers.
Thanks.

Comment: This sort of question is always easier to understand if you can explain why you want to know. It is possible that you have mis-understood, or mis-asked something critical. For example, does it interest you that the asm boot code may use registers to initialise clocks or memory controllers?

Comment: what if the first parameter is floating point, built for hard float?  is r0 used for that?

Comment: You really need to clarify and expand on this question to be clear what you mean.. Perhaps with some code disassembly examples.

Answer (score 2):

Your question probably needs more context to be clear what you are referring to, but the [ARM Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) defines how a *conforming* compiler uses specific registers  section 5.1.1 specifically.

R0 is used to hold the first argument of a function call, and to return the result value.  It may also be used arbitrarily as a scratch register to hold temporary or intermediate values within a function call.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
float fun ( float a )
{
    return(a+1.0F);
}
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   eddf7a01    vldr    s15, [pc, #4]   ; c <fun+0xc>
   4:   ee300a27    vadd.f32    s0, s0, s15
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

No r0 is not always used before anything else.